# How can I rename a Sheet in Altium Designer?

Tags: altium

I'm trying to rename a schematic sheet file inside Altium Designer 14 (in Project Panel).

The only way I can do it is renaming the sheet file in Windows Explorer and relink the file to the project. This is very time consuming and unproductive.

I found no way to do it directly in Altium. I tried the context menu, F2 shortcut and the File menu with no success.

Does someone knows if it can be done directly in the program? And how to do it?

Comment: An excellent question. I struggled with this very thing when I first began using Altium

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As mentioned, you can Save As, which saves a *copy* of your document. However, the correct way to do it is to open the Storage Manager panel (System-->Storage Manager):

[image]

[image]

From within the Storage Manager panel you can right-click on a file and choose "Rename".

I would show a picture of the storage manager but mine contains confidential files from my work, but I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried it. Nice. But after I have renamed one file, it was actually renamed, but then disappeared from the Storage manager :)

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. This simple feature is so hidden in the software! Just makes our lives harder.

Comment: @EugeneSh. My apologies, I completely missed your comment. When you rename a file it often doesn't update the project structure, so if there's a file that has a different name from the one that the project file is expecting to see, it is removed from the project (and thus, disappears from the storage manager). I think this might be a bug, or at least something that Altium should look into fixing

Comment: I have renamed a schematic sheet file through the storage manager.  It had updated the file name in the project tree.  It had *not* updated the file names assigned to the hierarchical blocks.

Comment: @NickAlexeev This is correct, I have had the same problem before. It does not automatically update the sheet name. As far as I know you have to go in and update it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the file in the Project panel and `Save As`. But then you will have to delete the file with the old name, anyway.

Comment: I can't belive that a powerful PCB software like Altium Designer does not have a basic feature like renaming a file.

Comment: Some features are realized there in such a way, that it is easier not to use them..

Comment: I use "save as" also. You can delete the old one, but you don't HAVE to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

it´s really simple, you just have to rename on your folder and then open the project again and it will be with the new name. if you want to change the name of a sheet into the project is the same process, when you open the project again you just have to move the sheet to the project again ;)

Answer (score 0):

Files such as schematic sheets can be renamed from within Altium using the `Storage Manager` window. The method for accessing the `Storage Manager` was changed in Altium 18.

To access the `Storage Manager` click on the `Panels` button on the bottom right of Altium.

[image]

Then click on `Storage Manager`

[image]

Inside of the `Storage Manager` you can right click your file under the `Project Files` heading and select rename (or hit `F2`).